# How do I read a csv file as json, then reading it as a list and remove selected list?

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, csv

I am currently testing out how to analyze the large CSV file with lots of data (like 30000 records)
The following image is part of the column that I would like to extract the wordings like "Animation", "Drama",＂Comedy" etc.

My proposed steps as below:

1. Open the CSV file and read it as json? so that the data would save in the list?
2. Use for-loop to loop over the whole column (I am not sure about this part)
3. Remove the list? or extract the wordings?

The following are 2 columns, there are still more columns but I would like to try to extract the words first.

[image]

[image]

sample data:

````json
[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
[{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 14, 'name': 'Fantasy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
[{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]
[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]
[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]```
````

Comment: Hi, can you please post the code you have written so far and a copy paste part of the data. So someone can reproduce your problem.

Comment: "Open the csv file and read it as json?" That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Your csv is not a csv, as far as I can tell. It seems like a json-lines format, but with a header, so not really json-lines. But if you throw out the header, it could be json-lines. What *created* this file?

Comment: I actually downloaded this file from kaggle, and then scraped the movie data from IMDB, then merged them together into one file.

Comment: Sorry I am new to coding so I have no idea of how to implement this..

Comment: @helpme that doesn't realyl tell me what you did to generate these files. I would fix whatever is creating them and use a more reasonable serialization format. In any case, you can just iterate over the lines skipping the header and use `json.loads`, and then create a dataframe out of that

Comment: Sorry do you expect people to manually type the data in that image to reproduce your issue?  Edit your question and paste in *actual text*.

Comment: Thank you for your help I will try figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct but it will not be that much efficient I would say, rather you can optimize your source to give the file in a proper way.

Try the below code, hope this will help.

```py
import ast, json
import pandas as pd
from csv import reader
file_name = 'test_file.csv'
data = []
with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    headings = next(csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:
        data.extend(ast.literal_eval(row[0]))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
out_df = df[df['name'].str.contains("Animation|Drama|Comedy")]
print(out_df)
```

You can just proceed from there, I hope.

Comment: Hello, the codes works out for me in the for loop part, however I would like to know that if I would like to add one more column, which is the unique key, what coding should I add to it?

Comment: it produce a result like

Comment: name
0      Animation
1         Comedy
2         Family
3      Adventure
4        Fantasy
         ...
40060      Drama
40061   Thriller

Comment: but how should i stack it up back (e.g 0 Animation 1 Comedy 2 Family, should be in the same row) but now they're in 3 rows

Answer (score -1):

Pandas can be a fast/powerful way to analyze a large csv.  There's likely a faster way to do it, but you could try something like:

```
import pandas as pd

main_col = 'genres'
sub_cols = ['name','id']
search_str = 'ANIMATION'

# read csv as pandas dataframe, using only the columns you care about, e.g. 'Genre'
df_csv = pd.read_csv(filename,usecols=[main_col])

movies = {}
# iterate over all rows
for index,row in df_csv.iterrows():
    # evaluate the string as a list of dicts
    row_as_list = eval(row)

    for dictionary in row_as_list:
        val = dictionary[subCols[0]]
        key = dictionary[subCols[1]]

        # filter for only the results you want
        if search_str in movie_name.upper():
            movies[key] = val
```

This will give you a dictonary that looks like:

```
movies = {
    '1': 'Movie1',
    '2': 'Movie2'
}
```

This is a valid solution to your problem, but if you stored the data in the csv a more reasonable way, i.e. only one name:id pair on each line, you could get a much faster and cleaner approach with pandas.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it. But im just wondering if I have to specify the column Genre to extract, do I need a for loop to run over the whole "Genres" column?

Comment: Fixed an error in my post fyi, current edit shows a working example.  The loop is essentially built-in, so df.loc is returning a dataframe with all rows selected that satisfy the condition (in this example, that the string "animation" is in the "name" column).  The last line in my example prints a dataframe; if you save that to a variable "df2" you could extract all the names to a list by saying list(df2['names'])

Comment: Okay I'm looking at the examples more closely, I misunderstood how they had been stored in the csv.  I'll adjust my answer to reflect that.